# Laravel: Many-to-Many between a model and a pivot, can't access relationship values

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working on a tool where I need to implement the following models:

[image]

There is a Many-to-Many between **Function** and **Location** and because each combination of Functions and Location can have multiple Cost Centers I create a Model for the pivot named: **LocationProfunction**. The pivot migration between Cost Centers and LocationProfunctions looks like this:

The pivot for the **Cost Center** and **LocationProfunction** migration:

```
Schema::create('cost_center_location_profunction', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cost_center_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_profunction_id');


        $table->foreign('cost_center_id')->references('id')->on('cost_centers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('location_profunction_id')->references('id')->on('location_profunction')->onDelete('cascade');
     
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Models:

```
class CostCenter extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function locationProfunctions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(LocationProfunction::class);
    }
}

class LocationProfunction extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function costCenters() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CostCenter::class);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to access the LocationProfunctions values from the Cost Center model like this:

```
$this->locationProfunctions
```

And I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'cost_center_location_profunction.' in 'field
> list' (SQL: select `location_profunction`.*,
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`cost_center_id` as
> `pivot_cost_center_id`, `cost_center_location_profunction`. `` as `pivot_` from `location_profunction` inner join `cost_center_location_profunction` on `location_profunction`.`id` = `cost_center_location_profunction`. `` where
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`cost_center_id` = 1) in file
> /home/vagrant/code/projectresourceonline/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
> on line 671

I explicitly change the model relationship to declare the pivot table and the foreign keys:

```
public function locationProfunctions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(LocationProfunction::class, 'cost_center_location_profunction', 'cost_center_id', 'location_profunction_id');
}
```

And the result looks good:

```
   {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 2",
        "locationProfunctions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "location_id": 6,
                "profunction_id": 1,
                "hourly_rate": 56,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null,
                "pivot": {
                    "cost_center_id": 2,
                    "location_profunction_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

But now I'm trying to get the Cost Center other way around(from the **Profunction** Model):

```
$profunction->load('projectRoles', 'locations');
    foreach ($profunction->locations as $location) {
       dump($location->pivot->costCenters()->get());
    }
```

And I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'cost_center_location_profunction.profunction_id'
> in 'field list' (SQL: select `cost_centers`.*,
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`profunction_id` as
> `pivot_profunction_id`,
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`cost_center_id` as
> `pivot_cost_center_id` from `cost_centers` inner join
> `cost_center_location_profunction` on `cost_centers`.`id` =
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`cost_center_id` where
> `cost_center_location_profunction`.`profunction_id` is null)

I update also this relationship to explicitly declare the relationship:

```
public function costCenters() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(CostCenter::class, 'cost_center_location_profunction', 'location_profunction_id', 'cost_center_id');
}
```

But now the result is an empty collection:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#470   #items: [] }

My guess is that I have a reflection related problem but I can't figure it out. Please help :D.

It's strange that this:
`dd(LocationProfunction::all());` return empty collection

Also, I'm open to other alternatives. I posted another question where I'm asking [if the solution that I want to implement is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602249/laravel-many-to-many-between-a-model-and-a-pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602249/laravel-many-to-many-between-a-model-and-a-pivot)

**EDITED:**
Snapshot with the "cost_center_location_profunction" table:
[image]

Snapshot with the location_profunction table:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the table `cost_center_location_profunction` doesn't exist for some reason ...

Comment: @shaedrich, thanks for your comment, I added a snapshot with the table

Comment: @shaedrich, for me is strage that Laravel is search for the column "location_profunction" in the table: "cost_center_location_profunction "

Comment: Your error message says, it's looking for `cost_center_location_profunction` or `cost_center_location_profunction.profunction_id`. In the second case, Laravel should use `location_profunction_id` but the way you set up your relationships should already take care of it.

Comment: That error is a red herring as the code for the error is not an good aproach to go through relationships through pivot.

Comment: @mrhn, thanks for your comment, Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: In your last example, what are the id of the cost center. Because that last relationship should work.

Comment: @mrhn, I don't understand what you need :D.

Comment: What is strange for me that this:   dd(LocationProfunction::all());, return empty collection

Comment: Then you got a problem? show location_profunction table?

Comment: @mrhn, Done, snapshot added

Comment: But if LocationProfunction::all()) returns empty, you are not connecting to that database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232631/discussion-between-mrhn-and-nicuvlad).